# Homebrew - How do I list all unlinked formulas?

Tags: homebrew

How do I list all installed but unlinked formulas of [Homebrew](https://brew.sh)?

Comment: What do you mean by "unlinked"? keg-only formulas, formulas where the linking failed, or something else?

Comment: @nohillside all of them. all of installed formulas that are not linked. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run `brew doctor`, which among other things, will show you all unlinked formulas.